# Where is hook code located?

Tags: redmine

I am quite new to Ruby/Redmine but I need to make some changes to a Redmine install.

Where is the hook code physically located? For example, in issues_helper.rb on line 283 I see:

```
call_hook(:helper_issues_show_detail_after_setting, {:detail => detail, :label => label, :value => value, :old_value => old_value })
```

I have done some reading but I must be missing something simple. I don't see where the actual hook code is located.

Cross posted: http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/40976

I am running Redmine v. 2.1.4.stable

Answer (score 0):

Hook code is located into plugins. [Here](https://github.com/twinslash/redmine_omniauth_google/blob/master/lib/redmine_omniauth_google/hooks.rb) is example.

If you would like to change smth in Redmine behavior (without changing sore) you should write a plugin. How to write plugins you can read here http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugin_Tutorial